# Trying to dual boot Windows XP pro with Windows 7 preinstalled

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot

I have a sony vaio VGNFW 590 with Windows 7 pre-installed. I need to dual boot Windows XP but when I  try to boot using usb I get an error`invalid boot.ini file` and then it shows that hal.dll is missing. I did a bit of google search and found out that older versions of windows should be install before installing later versions. Also that windows 7 doesn't have boot.ini file. Then I gave a try using a dvd but in that case windows setup starts and it loads the files until a point where I get a stop screen of death with `Stop: 0X0000007B (0XF78A6524, 0XC00000034, 0X00000000, 0x00000000)` Can anyone guide me to dual boot XP now ?

Answer (score 0):

When I did this for the first time I did it the 'wrong' way around too. The way I fixed it was to re-insert the win7 install media and hit 'Repair', this seems to replace the boot loader with the win7 one, which recognises both installations.

Comment: I don't have issues booting into windows 7 right now but can't install xp (i mean dual boot)

Comment: Oh so you can't even install XP? What medium are you installing it via?

Comment: trying to install xp using usb

Answer (score 0):

The error 0XC00000034 means a Storage driver was not found. You probably have Win7 installed in AHCI mode, so you need to load the SATA driver during setup via <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah finally I was successful dual booting windows 7 and windows xp. I had to slipstream the SATA driver using nLITE. Thanks for your time.

Comment: nice to hear that it worked. Mark the question as answered and the case is closed.